# Do Python programs still work the same as a standalone application?

Tags: python, windows, macos, export, py2exe

I wrote a university gradebook application for my friends and I. I want to share it with them but they don't have python, so I was going to make it a standalone application. First - what exporter would be best so that both my Mac OS X friends and Windows friends could use my program? Second - I am using imports (listed below), would they work in the exported executable application? Third - I am using text files outside of the program to store data. Would the text file creation/reading/writing still work in the exported executable application? Sorry for all the questions, but everything I've read has been somewhat ambiguous, so I figured I'd ask the Stackoverflow experts.

Imports:

```
import requests, time, os, linecache, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Initial interaction with the file:

```
def informationFile():
global saveFile, fileCheck
try:
    with open("Information.txt") as file:
        print "Login File Loaded"
except IOError:
    saveFile = open("Information.txt", "w")
    print "Login File Created"
fileCheck = os.path.getsize("Information.txt")
readFile = open("Information.txt", "r")
```

Thanks in advance, Jackson

Comment: There are ways you can distribute the python program. Look at py2exe, distutils.

Comment: both bbfreeze ans cx_free claim to support Windows and OSX

Comment: OS X has Python by default, but not BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say anything abt Mac, but on Windows the simplest way to me was Nuitka.
According to my tests it can't build absolutely standalone app, python27.dll still needed, but that's the only and reasonable dependence